# Problema con Node RED

Tags: nodejs, arduino

Estoy conectando un Arduino a través de MQTT a Node RED. Este arduino me manda el siguiente string "Temperatura:28.0". Luego tengo otra placa que obtiene la humedad y la duelve en forma de string "Humedad:50". A la hora de recibir los datos por Node RED me llegan los string, pero no soy capaz de transformarlos a JSON, ya que lo tengo que entregar a dweet.io para visualizar los datos, y este programa me pide JSON.

A ver si me podéis echar una mano!

Answer (score 1):

realmente no se mucho de de arduinos, pero en nodejs hay una forma de hacer lo que quieres, he ideado un metodo que te devuelve un objeto dado un arreglo de strings de la forma `abcd:123'

```js
 function getValue (arrayString) {
        var obj = {};
        arrayString.forEach((string) => {
            var elementIndex = 0
            for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                if(string[i] == ':') {
                    elementIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            str = string.substring(0, elementIndex);
            val = string.substring(elementIndex+1, string.length)
            obj[str] =  parseFloat(val, 10);
        });
        return obj;
    }

    arrayString = [
        'Temperatura:28.0',
        'Humedad:50',
    ]
    
    var obj = getValue(arrayString);
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Si llamas a getValue con tu arreglo de string deberia devolverte un objeto de la forma que quieres, si lo quieres como string llama a `JSON.stringify(obj)`.
Espero que mi respuesta te ayude

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `JSON.parse()` para generar un json a partir de una cadena de texto.

Aunque primero tendrás que arreglar un poco la cadena de texto
`Temperatura:28.0` debería quedar `{"Temperatura":"28.0"}`

Este código de ejemplo en una función te haría la conversión:[image: esquema ejemplo]

La función aquí:

```
var tmp1 = msg.payload.split(":");
msg.tmp1 = tmp1
msg.tmp2 = '{"'+tmp1[0]+'":"'+tmp1[1]+'"}'
msg.tmp3 = JSON.parse(msg.tmp2)
msg.payload = msg.tmp3
return msg;
```

El código de ejemplo (copiar importar en node-red)

```
[{"id":"f3968eda.9433c","type":"inject","z":"bdb4e3f1.7d752","name":"","topic":"","payload":"Temperatura:28.0","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":130,"y":570,"wires":[["1b9f2e72.43e04a","b1d9465e.22143"]]},{"id":"1b9f2e72.43e04a","type":"debug","z":"bdb4e3f1.7d752","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":true,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":205,"y":625,"wires":[]},{"id":"b1d9465e.22143","type":"function","z":"bdb4e3f1.7d752","name":"","func":"var tmp1 = msg.payload.split(\":\");\nmsg.tmp1 = tmp1\nmsg.tmp2 = '{\"'+tmp1[0]+'\":\"'+tmp1[1]+'\"}'\nmsg.tmp3 = JSON.parse(msg.tmp2)\nmsg.payload = msg.tmp3\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":295,"y":570,"wires":[["20d5fe8f.2ac472","26ececc1.a5f984"]]},{"id":"20d5fe8f.2ac472","type":"debug","z":"bdb4e3f1.7d752","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","x":390,"y":625,"wires":[]},{"id":"26ececc1.a5f984","type":"debug","z":"bdb4e3f1.7d752","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":true,"complete":"payload","targetType":"msg","x":455,"y":570,"wires":[]}]
```